Firebase Phone Auth not sending OTP to real Phone Numbers
My flutter web app not sending OTP to real numbers, It's only sending OTP to testing numbers. recapthcha enabled because sometime its showing to verify captcha.
firebase console--> authentication--> sign in method--> phone enabled
debug console error - Verification failed: error
production web - Unable to send OTP
class FirebaseAuthentication {
  late String verificationId;

  Future<void> sendOTP(String phoneNumber, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+91$phoneNumber',
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
          print('Verification completed');
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          print('Verification failed: ${e.message}');
          showErrorMessage(context, 'Unable to send OTP');
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
          print('Code sent: $verificationId');
          this.verificationId = verificationId;
          showOTPSentMessage(phoneNumber, context);
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          print('Auto retrieval timeout: $verificationId');
        },
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print('Firebase Auth Exception: ${e.message}');
      if (context.mounted) {
        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
          showErrorMessage(context, 'Invalid phone number');
        } else {
          showErrorMessage(context, 'Unable to send OTP');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('General Exception: $e');
      showErrorMessage(context, 'Unable to send OTP');
    }
  }

  void showOTPSentMessage(String phoneNumber, BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('OTP Sent to +91 $phoneNumber'),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    if (context.mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }

  void showErrorMessage(BuildContext context, String message) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    );
    if (context.mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }

  void authenticate(String otp, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: otp,
      );

      UserCredential authResult =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      if (context.mounted) {
        if (authResult.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser ?? false) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const userName()),
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const NumSelection(
                      userName: '',
                    )),
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (context.mounted) {
        const snackBar = SnackBar(
          content: Text('Wrong OTP. Please try again.'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }
    }
  }
}

It should send OTP to  real phone numbers

I think google has limited that function to the blaze package (pay as you go). The free tier spark package no longer have sms otp function. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#phone-auth
